# Column People Picker Required

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, administration, people-picker

I would like to know how I can set the "people picker" field to be non-required.

I tried to use advanced settings to set non-required but it isn't worked.
Someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit column and uncheck "Requirement that this column contains information". Would this fix the issue? Also have a try to change a browser or clean browser cache if the issue persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank as well, this works

Answer (score 0):

Try below approaches:

**Modern experience**:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on person or group column header > select **Column settings** > select **Edit**:

   [image]
3. Click on **More options** in column settings panel at the right side
4. Set **Require that this column contains information** to **No** and click Save button.

   [image]

---

**Classic experience**:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on Settings  (gear) icon at top right corner > select **List settings**
3. Scroll down to **Columns** section on list settings page and click on the person or group column name. It will open column settings page
4. On column settings page, set **Require that this column contains information** to **No** and click **OK** button at the bottom of page:

   [image]

Comment: Thank as well, this works

Comment: Great glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.